# Get result of compilation as single file with ASDF

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp, asdf

Is it possible to tell ASDF that it should produce only one `fas(l)` file for entire system? This file should be concatenation (in right order) of all compiled files of the system, including all files of systems on which target system depends.

Comment: I advise against this if you somehow have side-effects that happen outside the loading of your binary files.  E.g., if one of your ASDF systems does an implementation-dependent `require`, it won't happen when the concatenated binary is loaded, and the best clue you'll get are errors of unknown packages or style warnings of undefined functions (later, runtime errors).  That said, the single binary may be worth exploring on a case-by-case basis for big systems.  It's not like you'll save much time or space with this approach.  If you have a common base, you can dump an image to save time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with `compile-bundle-op` (ASDF 3.1): http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Predefined-operations-of-ASDF.html

*edit:* Actually, `monolithic-compile-bundle-op` seemes to be asked for (as shown in other answers).

Answer (score 2):

If you have to predict the extension, use `uiop:compile-file-type`.
And/or you can just call `(asdf:output-files 'asdf:monolithic-compile-bundle-op :my-system)` to figure out what is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Option `monolithic-compile-bundle-op` will create single compiled file which includes all dependencies, while `compile-bundle-op` creates a file for every system.

Example of use:

```
(asdf:operate 'asdf:monolithic-compile-bundle-op :my-system)
```

This command will create file `my-system--all-systems.fas(l)` in output directory of target project, as well as "bundle" files for every system, named like `my-system--system.fas(l)`.